# Clickable embed PDF

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to embed a clickable PDF in the body of email.

This code does embed PDF on the body of email but when I double click on image PDF file does not open.

Is there anyway I can have clickable image?

```
Public Sub InsetObject()
    Dim Inspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim Selection As Word.Selection
    Dim Email As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim LinkToFile As Object


    Set Email = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With Email
        .To = "XXX@XXXXX.com"
        .Subject = "XXX Dashboard"
        .Attachments.Add ("C:\Work\Daily Dashboard.pdf")
        .Display

         Set Inspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
         Set wdDoc = Inspector.WordEditor
         Set Selection = wdDoc.Application.Selection

         Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="AcroExch.Document.11", _
                   FileName:="C:\Work\Daily Dashboard.pdf", _
                   LinkToFile:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False

        .Send

    End With

    Set Inspector = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set Selection = Nothing
End Sub
```